# "Open in New Tab" not opening correct page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a HTML table and on each row there is a link to another page.

The `href` attribute is not used for this redirect. Rather an `onclick` event.

This works perfect when a **left-click** is used. However it does not work if "**right-click -> new tab**" is used. The current page just loads.

Is there any simple way of making it work with a right-click? Or do I have to remove the `href` (...which will remove the right click menu option).

```
<a onclick="CommCenter.Core.View.openRuleUrl('/Rule/Index/7256')" href="#">
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a target method?
<a onclick="CommCenter.Core.View.openRuleUrl('/Rule/Index/7256')" href="#" target="_self">

I may be wrong though

Comment: It fails because the href points to the current page. That is why using JavaScript for navigation is normally a bad idea.

Comment: What does CommCenter.Core.View.openRuleUrl do?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<a onclick="CommCenter.Core.View.openRuleUrl('/Rule/Index/7256')" href="/Rule/Index/7256">
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the prefix ends up <http://localhost> instead of <http://localhost/******.******.Web>

Comment: ...apologies, I can't figure out how to write bare Urls in this editor. Hope above makes some sense